# CakePHP 2.4.7 / AclExtras / aco_sync no database connection

Tags: php, database, cakephp, acl

When I execute this command in my app path "./Console/cake acl_extras.acl_extras aco_sync" and I get the error, that this output:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.7 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: l:\server\htdocs\test\app\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
#0 L:\server\htdocs\test\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(260): Mysql
->connect()
```

but the database connection is working

Comment: did you find a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but Cake's console was using a different `php.ini`. In that `php.ini`, the extension `php_pdo_mysql.dll` was commented out.

Once the extension was no longer commented out, the error disappeared.

**Update**

This was based on a WAMP installation. If you run a PHP script with only `phpinfo()`, you should find the following row:

- Loaded Configuration File

In my case, it displays: `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini`. This was the ini file to modify.

Comment: that was the problem I have too.

Comment: But I switched fro CakePHP to Laravel and from Laravel to my own, and from my own to Ruby on Rails. An with Ruby on Rails I have no problems.

Comment: This answer deserves half an upvote, because it seems you helped someone. But how did you identify where the alternate `php.ini` is? I tried modifying the only one I know of this way, with no success.

Comment: @ctlockey thanks for the advice, I have modified my answer. HTH!